# ASP.NETand TFS: Getting TF30076 Error

Tags: asp.net

i'm developing an ASP.NET application to deal with TFS server programmatically to list all TFS projects and give the ability to add work items to any TFS project. if i run the application locally using visual studio local host --> every this is running as required.

if i host the application on my iis , i face the following error :

TF30076: The server name {tfsServerName} provided does not correspond to a server URI that can be found. Confirm that the server name is correct.

i don't know what is the difference between the two cases.

any help please ?????

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this question: [ASP.NET-MVC and TFS: Getting TF30076 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122529/asp-net-mvc-and-tfs-getting-tf30076-error)